# Find all $(x,y)$ satisfying $(\sin^2x+\frac{1}{\sin^2 x})^2+(\cos^2x+\frac{1}{\cos^2 x})^2=12+\frac{1}{2}\sin y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Find all pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers that satisfy the equation $(\sin^2x+\frac{1}{\sin^2 x})^2+(\cos^2x+\frac{1}{\cos^2 x})^2=12+\frac{1}{2}\sin y$

---

I supposed $a=\sin^2x$ and $b=\cos^2x$
So the equation becomes $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2+(b+\frac{1}{b})^2=12+\frac{1}{2}\sin y$
As $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$ and $b+\frac{1}{b}\geq 2$
$12+\frac{1}{2}\sin y\geq 8$
$\sin y\geq -8$
I am stuck here.I could not solve further.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: $a+b=1$ may help.

Comment: I will wager looking at the graph that if you attempt to calculate the range of the LHS the minimum value will be exactly $12.5$, which matches with the maximum value of the RHS.  The question then becomes for what values of $x$ is $12.5$ achieved.

Comment: See https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060821004533AAIoOlv

Comment: This question is a pitfall,i think.It appears its minimum value is $8$,but actually its minimum value is $12.5$,if we closely examine.

Comment: @diya, actually, there is no pitfall, if every step along the way, you preserve the expressions at the equality case. When you stated $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq2$ and $b+\frac{1}{b}\geq2$, you weakened the condition at the equality case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As JMoravitz notes in the comments, it's probably the case that the minimum value of the LHS is 12.5. Let's prove this.

Using the inequality $a^2+b^2\ge\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}$, note that
\begin{align*}\left(\sin^2x + \frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)^2 + \left(\cos^2x + \frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^2&\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin^2x + \frac{1}{\sin^2x} + \cos^2x + \frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}\right)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{4}{(2\sin x\cos x)^2}\right)^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{4}{\sin^2{2x}}\right)^2\\
&\ge\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{4}{1}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{2}.
\end{align*}
I leave it to you to determine when this equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding $(a + \frac{1}{a})^2 + (b + \frac{1}{b})^2 = 12 + \sin y$
will get us $a^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{a^2} + b^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{b^2} = 12 + \sin y$.

And we can subtract 4 from both sides.
$a^2 + b^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} = 8 + \frac{1}{2}\sin y$

Now make y as a function of x:
$y = asin(2a^2 + 2b^2 + \frac{2}{a^2} + \frac{2}{b^2} - 16)$

Substitute back a and b to get
$y = asin(2sin^4x + 2cos^4x + 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x - 16)$

Because $asin(x)$ is only defined for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we can say that
$0 \leq 2sin^4x + 2cos^4x + 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x - 16 \leq 1$ or $16 \leq 2sin^4x + 2cos^4x + 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x \leq 17$.

Now we can complete the square with $2sin^4x + 2cos^4x$ to get $16 \leq 2(sin^2x + cos^2x)^2 - 4sin^2xcos^2x + 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x \leq 17$.
This reduces to $16 \leq 2 - 4sin^2xcos^2x + 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x \leq 17$ which can be rewritten as $14 \leq 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x - 4sin^2xcos^2x \leq 15$.

Using some trigonometric identities we get $14 \leq 2sec^4x + 2csc^4x - sin^2(2x) \leq 15$.

So we have y as a function of x, we have the domain, and we have the range.

Comment: Use `\sin` for trigonometric functions in LaTeX.

Comment: @Element118 thx for the advice